# What tool do you use to convert the datasets (in .csv) into database tables?

Tags: pandas, pandasql

I have lots of `.csv` files. I should write `SQL` querys using `Pandasql`.
Before, i take my query into the code, i wish to run it in a database to make sure its output is exactly what i want.

Therefore, i need to find a solution to convert these `.csv` files into tables in database.

If you have same experience, then:

What tools do you use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on database you use. In PostgreSQL I am using:

```
COPY table_nname FROM '/path/to/csv/ZIP_CODES.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

With MySQL:

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --local -u root -p Database TableName.csv
```